# Unbundle Bundle-NativeCode at install time for Eclipse RCP

Tags: java, osgi, eclipse-rcp

Dynamic libraries can be included inside Eclipse plug-ins, referenced with Bundle-NativeCode in MANIFEST.MF, and automatically extracted at runtime to a temporary, user-writable location.

There are some security concerns with copying executable code at runtime to a user-writable location.

**Is there a way to instead install them already extracted, alongside the application, and use these installed, unzipped DLLs instead?**

Is there a way to do this without installing as unzipped every bundle that includes a DLL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do this using Bundle-NativeCode.

You could do something like the SWT code which uses `System.loadLibrary`.

You can include the libraries in a directory in the RCP install using the `root` directive in a feature `build.properties`. Your plugin can use `Platform.getInstallLocation` to find the install location.

Comment: I do that for some of my own plug-ins. But I have some third-party plug-ins that include DLLs referenced with Bundle-NativeCode.